# Good accuracy but bad prediction on keras mode

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-classification

I am pretty new to Machine Learning, and I am trying to use Google Colab with Tensorflow/Keras to train an image classification model using transfer learning (Resnet50).

I started by using image datasets, using the following code:

```
data_root = '/tmp/OCT2017'
 
batch_size = 32
img_height = 160
img_width = 160
 
data_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data_root + '/train',labels='inferred',
                                                                 image_size=(img_height,img_width),
                                                                 batch_size=batch_size)
```

For small testing datasets, this worked pretty well, and I got both good accuracy and good predictions.
But while trying to use larger datasets, all the RAM provided by Colab was consumed, so I switched to generators, using:

```
data_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()

data_train_gen = data_generator.flow_from_directory(data_root + '/train',
                                                target_size=(img_height,img_width),
                                                class_mode='sparse',
                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                shuffle=False)
```

and trained the model using:

```
base_learning_rate = 0.0001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  epochs = 10
  history =model.fit(
    data_train_gen,
    validation_data=data_val_gen,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[csv_logger]
  )
```

I got good accuracy using this setup:

```
model.evaluate(data_test)
```

> 31/31 [==============================] - 3s 93ms/step - loss: 0.0925 - accuracy: 0.9742

> [0.09248838573694229, 0.9741735458374023]

However, when asking for predictions, in order to make a confusion matrix, I got awful results

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns

y_pred = model.predict(data_test)
predicted_categories = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in data_test_gen], axis=0)

cm = confusion_matrix(predicted_categories, true_categories)

heatmap = sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cmap='YlGn', xticklabels=['CNV','DME','DRUSEN','NORMAL'],yticklabels=['CNV','DME','DRUSEN','NORMAL'])
plt.xlabel("True Labels")
plt.ylabel("Predictions")
plt.show()
```

The predictions were around 40% correct
The confusion matrix appeared completely random

```
classification_report(true_categories, predicted_categories, target_names=class_names, output_dict=True)
```

> {'CNV': {'f1-score': 0.256198347107438,
> 'precision': 0.256198347107438,
> 'recall': 0.256198347107438,
> 'support': 242},
> 'DME': {'f1-score': 0.23236514522821577,
> 'precision': 0.23333333333333334,
> 'recall': 0.23140495867768596,
> 'support': 242},
> 'DRUSEN': {'f1-score': 0.25311203319502074,
> 'precision': 0.25416666666666665,
> 'recall': 0.25206611570247933,
> 'support': 242},
> 'NORMAL': {'f1-score': 0.2827868852459016,
> 'precision': 0.2804878048780488,
> 'recall': 0.28512396694214875,
> 'support': 242},
> 'accuracy': 0.256198347107438,
> 'macro avg': {'f1-score': 0.256115602694144,
> 'precision': 0.25604653799637167,
> 'recall': 0.256198347107438,
> 'support': 968},
> 'weighted avg': {'f1-score': 0.256115602694144,
> 'precision': 0.2560465379963717,
> 'recall': 0.256198347107438,
> 'support': 968}}

Comment: Are you sure you don't shuffle the testing data?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am sure I don't shuffle the testing data. All datasets and generators have the same code, I just change the path termination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not show your test generator but make sure you set shuffle=False. What is the difference between data_test and data_test_gen? If you have a test generator called data_test you can get the true labels from

```
true_categories=data_test.labels
```

Then use these in the confusion matrix and classification report

Comment: Hello. I should have explained that data_test and data_test_gen are similar to data_train and data_train_gen, I just changed the path to the files.

Comment: This worked for me! I have no idea why, but I guess somehow the true labels got mixed. Thank you for the help